# Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'iMin'

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
double a[10] = { 1.2, 2.5, 34.1, 21.4, 5, 12.1, 7.6, 8.2, 7, 10 }, min = a[0], max = a[0];
    int iMax, iMin;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (a[i] > max) {
            max = a[i];
            iMax = i;
        }
        if (a[i] < min) {
            min = a[i];
            iMin = i;
        }
    }

    cout << iMin;
```

> Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'iMin' is being used without
>   being initialized.

В чем может быть проблема? Еще иногда в консоль выскакивает число большое, отрицательное: -8.......

Comment: Компилятор вам детально описал проблему. Вы не понимаете, что он говорит?

Comment: @AnT, я же инициализировал переменные

Comment: и где же вы их инициализировали? посмотрите ещё раз повнимательнее

Comment: Где? `iMax, iMin` у вас не инициализированы.